# How should I assign RGB colors to points in the Mandelbrot Set?

Tags: fractals

I decided to learn about the Canvas object in javascript by implementing a display of the Mandelbrot Set.

I am mimicking the [Mandelbrot psuedocode found on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#For_programmers). The thrust of it is that the number of iterations it takes for a point to diverge is proportional to the color that is assigned to that point. However, in javascript, colors are represented in three dimensions, which one dimension (with values from 0 to 255) for the red, blue, and green channels. Obviously when I assign the same values to each channel, I get a boring image in shades of grey.

I was wondering, how would one map this "number of iterations to diverge" into the RGB space and make it look more interesting?

Comment: Perhaps use the HSV color space instead of RGB?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513690/map-rainbow-colors-to-rgb

Comment: @ChrisPhan, Your comments led me in the right direction. HSL made it super-easy to have better looking output. Do you guys think I should delete me question?

Comment: Don't delete questions without good reason - especially if they provide an answer (even if it's in the comments).  Someone in the future might make good use of the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: generated image]

As Chris Phan pointed out in the comments, I used the HSL colour space and it looked great.

Comment: What formulas did you use for HSL values to get this result?

Answer (score 1):

I use simple algorithm based on sine function and change frequency and phase shift for every color component - below fragment of code in **Swift**

```
red = UInt8((sin(self.freqRed * unit * mandelColor + self.phaseRed) + 1) / 2 * 255.0)
green = UInt8((sin(self.freqGreen * unit * mandelColor + self.phaseGreen) + 1) / 2 * 255.0)
blue = UInt8((sin(self.freqBlue * unit * mandelColor + self.phaseBlue) + 1) / 2 * 255.0)
```

[image: Also attach sample picture]

Comment: Amazing. I love swift and your color gamut is very striking. Thank you a million.